# How to auto-scale <svg> element and contents? (d3.js)

Tags: html, css, d3.js

Is it possible to scale the svg element (and all i's contents accordingly) without having clipping? I've tried scaling the svg to 100% width and height however the contents are being clipped.

The svg is generated via d3.js

HTML

```
<svg>
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="red"></circle>
</svg>
```

CSS

```
svg {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It depends on the context, the HTML document where you put your svg. Some code (html/css) to show us ?

Comment: just added an example snippet

Comment: Yes but we need the document HTML and CSS to see how you can do in your case.

Comment: There's nothing more in your HTML, the whole document is only a svg tag ?

Comment: yes, this is for example purposes, is it important right now?

Comment: Yes, because if you use percentage, it means that it will depend on the width / height container. And as you can see, we don't know that information.

Comment: it's ok, I want it to fully scale at this point. Regardless of the rest of the document, if a solution works, it works.

Comment: You seem kinda rude for someone who need help and don't know basic html.

Answer (score -1):

Ohh ok, I get it :

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="red"></circle>
</svg>
```

This means : **width = 100px, not 100%**.
Same for circle attribute, cx="50" means coordinate X = 50px, not 50%.

**What you can do :**

**HTML**

```
<svg class="scaled-svg">
  <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="20%" fill="red"></circle>
</svg>
```

**CSS**

```
.scaled-svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto; /* or 100% but it can break the ratio */
}
```

With that code, the SVG will

Comment: it's not different than what I do there, did you test your solution? It also doesn't scale the content (just the container is scaled) http://cssdeck.com/labs/aawnlsfj

Comment: Because you putted coordinates with an absolute unit (px), instead of percents : http://cssdeck.com/labs/2wbcy8xh

Comment: d3.js unfortunately generates only pixels.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351244/convert-result-to-percentage-in-d3